Which are or were those ideas considered "natural rights"?
Before the appearence of the idea of "human rights" after the second world war (though some says not the term but a similar term and a similar idea, "rights of the man" appeared after the French Revolution), the predominant idea was that of "natural rights". But unlike "human rights", it isnt easy or I dont know if a list exists citing which ideas represent each individual "natural right". I know more or less the general idea of "natural rights", but I dont know each individual idea which represents each "natural right".
Which are or were those ideas considered "natural rights"?

Natural rights and legal rights.

Does this answer your question? What is the Difference Between Human Rights and Natural Rights?

Cicero, medievil scholars, Hobbes, Locke, and Rousseau (the latter three being the most prominent proponents of natural law theory IMHO) had very different ideas about what to count among them. I think it would help if you asked separate questions for each philosopher that sounds interesting for you when you read up on them.

There is no single such list, different writers throughout the ages considered different rights as inalienable, typically as a reflection of contemporary thinking due to changes to the balance or structure of political powers at the time.
Human rights are more political than philosophical, in that by declaring them, a government is bound to protect them, whereas natural rights defined by any philosopher may be ignored as irrelevant by any specific government.
In politics, declaring a right as a human right typically means a government cannot (easily) change or violate it, as opposed to other rights which are changed by simply enacting new laws.

Well, there's no one master list of natural rights because natural rights are an ad hoc set of rights based on many various [natural law theories (SEP)] and their interpretations2. Law is an obtuse topic even for the philosopher to dissect because it's just as complicated as any notion of mathematics or science. Consequently philosophers of law have their work cut out for them. The SEP has all sorts of articles on various taxonomies of rights impacted by natural rights (which are distinct from the rights people come up with out of expedience):

Human Rights (SEP)
Group Rights (SEP)
Legal Rights (SEP)
Civil Rights (SEP)
Children Rights (SEP)
Natural Law and Ethics

And today, there are a number of legal philosophies that emerge out of jurisprudence that interact with natural law also. There's legal positivism, critical theory, etc. Thus, natural law is a very complex umbrella, and we should first provide a definition from the WP article natural law:

Natural law1 (Latin: ius naturale, lex naturalis) is a system of law based on a close observation of natural order and human nature, from which values, thought by natural law's proponents to be intrinsic to human nature, can be deduced and applied independently of positive law (the express enacted laws of a state or society).2 According to the theory of law called jusnaturalism, all people have inherent rights, conferred not by act of legislation but by "God, nature, or reason".3 Natural law theory can also refer to "theories of ethics, theories of politics, theories of civil law, and theories of religious morality".

To boot, natural law goes back to the origins of philosophy itself! Thus, not only are there various current theories, but these sorts of theories extend back for thousands of years. From the article natural rights and legal rights:

Natural law first appeared in ancient Greek philosophy,2 and was referred to by Roman philosopher Cicero. It was subsequently alluded to in the Bible,3 and then developed in the Middle Ages by Catholic philosophers such as Albert the Great, his pupil Thomas Aquinas, and Jean Gerson in his 1402 work "De Vita Spirituali Animae."4 During the Age of Enlightenment, the concept of natural laws was used to challenge the divine right of kings, and became an alternative justification for the establishment of a social contract, positive law, and government – and thus legal rights – in the form of classical republicanism. Conversely, the concept of natural rights is used by others to challenge the legitimacy of all such establishments.

We can take a couple of examples including the US Constitution which sought to enshrine some of those natural rights and the Universal Declaration of Human Rights. Think about how odd it is to talk of freedom and natural rights, to devise a Bill of Rights but at the same time enshrine slavery as an institution. Should the right to own slaves as endorsed by the Bible be considered a natural right? And how universal is the Universal Declaration?
From the declaration:
- Articles 1–2 establish the basic concepts of dignity, liberty, and equality.
- Articles 3–5 establish other individual rights, such as the right to life and the prohibition of slavery and torture.
- Articles 6–11 refer to the fundamental legality of human rights with specific remedies cited for their defence when violated.
- Articles 12–17 set forth the rights of the individual towards the community, including freedom of movement and residence within each state, the right of property, the right to a nationality and right to asylum.
- Articles 18–21 sanction the so-called "constitutional liberties" and spiritual, public, and political freedoms, such as freedom of thought, opinion, expression, religion and conscience, word, peaceful association of the individual, and receiving and imparting information and ideas through any media.
- Articles 22–27 sanction an individual's economic, social and cultural rights, including healthcare. It upholds an expansive right to an adequate standard of living, and makes special mention of care given to those in motherhood or childhood.
- Articles 28–30 establish the general means of exercising these rights, the areas in which the rights of the individual cannot be applied, the duty of the individual to society, and the prohibition of the use of rights in contravention of the purposes of the United Nations Organization.[15]

So, the closest to a list of human rights you might get is the UN's list. It had no serious objections from the various governments of the world, and is frequently appealed to as a virtuous document. But something like universal assent to its inviolability might be hard to come by.

First off, the list must be dependent on divine premises (whether of Natural spirits or of GOD), otherwise one cannot claim an idea of any natural rights at all.  (Evolution does not grant any rights at all.)  So anyone claiming to have rights is implicitly calling on the Divine world or on the premises held by people in history (largely based on Biblical history).
So, I'll attempt a list for our world:

the right to have restful sleep (temperature, noise, surface hardness/softness, sufficiently secure, etc.)
the right to eat and drink foods one needs
the right to eliminate waste
the right to breathe oxygenated air (not polluted)
the right to form relationship with others
the right to reproduce

This last one could be removed for those who have broken the law,  but then you need to add the right to appeal a case before the Law until you understand your error (or the Law understands their own).

+1 Not sure why this is downvoted so heavily, this is in the vein of the way the founding fathers of America would think through the issue of "natural rights," as I understand it. Another one I've heard is that they considered defending one's own home to be a natural right, because in nature, animals defend their homes (I think their basis for what we would call the "castle doctrine").  But yes, this view must be underpinned by belief in God (e.g., Bible and fallen nature), because nature taken alone is often reprehensible.
